# Initialise in a switch statement in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I want to do a menu with the following options:

- add a new product
- add a new customer
- give the product out
- give the customer out

i made a switch case for that (i will only write down the cases for the product, since the ones for the customer are basically the same):

```
switch(selection) {  
     case 1:    
            System.out.println("Name of the product:");  
            String productname = in.nextLine();  
            System.out.println("Productnumber:");    
            int productnumber = in.nextInt();  
     case 3:  
            System.out.println("Product: "+ productname);  
            System.out.println("Productnumber: "+ productnumber); 
}
```

If i try to compile that, i get the message that the productname and the productnumber in case 3 are not initialised. I declared those above the switch menu as a string for the productname and as an integer for the productnumber. How can i initialise them, if i ask for the value of those in case 1?

In case 3 i also have to check if something was typed in for the productname or the number. My idea would be to do an If-Statement. If something was typed in, then it has to give the product name  and number out, but i dont really know how to check if something was typed in for the productname.
Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If `selection == 3`, you never enter case 1, therefore never declaring the variables. You should declare them before entering the switch, and maybe give them relevant values at some point before.

If you loop around this switch and enter sequentially case 1 then case 3, the problem remains, because the variables you declared in case 1 are destroyed as soon as you leave the switch, before looping and entering it again.

Try something like:

```
String productname = "something";
int productNumber = 0; // something else

while(/*some test*/) { // the loop is only here to make my point

    switch(selection) {  
         case 1:    
                System.out.println("Name of the product:");  
                productname = in.nextLine();  
                System.out.println("Productnumber:");    
                productnumber = in.nextInt();  
                // break; ?
         case 3 :
                System.out.println("Product: "+ productname);  
                System.out.println("Productnumber: "+ productnumber); 
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

entering `case 1` is optional (just like an `if` statement) so you need to initialise them before switch (I'd say straight after declaration maybe?). Another thing (unrelated to your problem but important) is that you're not using `break;` in each case which will cause fall-through (if you hit `case 1` you'll go to `case 3` anyway).

Answer (score 0):

> i get the message that the productname and the productnumber in case 3 are not initialised

Correct, they are not initialized.  You initialize them in `case 1`, but not in `case 3`.  The compiler is smart enough to know that it can't guarantee `case 1` will always execute before `case 3`.  (Are `case` blocks in Java mutually exclusive by default?  If so, then it can guarantee that `case 1` will *never* execute before `case 3`.  I don't think they are, though, in which case you might want to investigate the use of `break` statements.)

Thus, you can't use a variable in `case 3` which only gets a value in `case 1`.

> I declared those above the switch menu

Not according to the code you posted you didn't.  They're *declared* inside of `case 1`:

```
case 1    
    System.out.println("Name of the product:");  
    string productname = in.nextLine();  
    System.out.println("Productnumber:");    
    int productnumber = in.nextInt();
```

In order to use them in other `case` blocks, they need to be declared outside of the `switch`:

```
String productname;
int productnumber;

switch(selection) {  
    case 1:   
        System.out.println("Name of the product:");  
        productname = in.nextLine();  
        System.out.println("Productnumber:");    
        productnumber = in.nextInt();  
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Product: "+ productname);  
        System.out.println("Productnumber: "+ productnumber);
```

In order to guarantee that they have a value in any given `case` block, they need to be initialized before any given `case` block.  The easiest way to do that is to provide a default value when declaring them:

```
String productname = null;
int productnumber = 0;

switch(selection) {  
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Name of the product:");  
        productname = in.nextLine();  
        System.out.println("Productnumber:");    
        productnumber = in.nextInt();  
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Product: "+ productname);  
        System.out.println("Productnumber: "+ productnumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need fields, or at least local variables outside the menu loop, asking `selection`.

```
        String productname = "N/A";  
        int productnumber = "N/A";  


switch (selection) {  
case 1:
     System.out.println("Name of the product:");  
     productname = in.nextLine();  
     System.out.println("Productnumber:");    
     productnumber = in.nextInt();  
     break;
case 3:  
     System.out.println("Product: "+ productname);  
     System.out.println("Productnumber: "+ productnumber); 
     break;
```

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure to add : to your case statements.

```
case 1: //Insert case statements
```

You can initialize when you declare them like so:

```
String productname = "";
```